# How many Katamino solutions are there on a $5 \times 12$ board?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, tiling, polyomino

Katamino is the puzzle of placing twelve polygonal pieces so as to form a $5\times 12$ rectangular array. The pieces consist of all possible arrangements of five connected $1\times 1$ squares. For example, there is the $5\times 1$ piece, the T piece, and so forth.

Here is one possible solution of the Katamino puzzle:
[image]

**Question.** How many Katamino solutions are there on a $5 \times 12$ board? Answers are also welcome for other sized boards (but specify the piece set).

I know that there must be at least four ways to arrange the pieces because I have successfully arranged them in one way, and this arrangement can be flipped horizontally, vertically, or in both directions to create new arrangements. For the same reason, because of this symmetry, the total number of arrangements must be a multiple of four. But how many solutions are there?

Comment: Visualizations: https://pentomino-tilings.netlify.app/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 1010 such tilings. The key term here is **polyominoes**; for the case of five squares glued along their edges, these are called **pentominoes**. Googling will yield lots more; see also the classic book of SW Golomb.

For this particular question, see e.g. [**here**](http://www.recmath.com/PolyPages/PolyPages/index.htm?Polyominoes.html) for an [**enumeration**](http://www.recmath.com/PolyPages/PolyPages/Pictures1/5x12.gif) of all of them.

Comment: Your number is the number of solutions up to symmetry, right? The total number should be 4040.

Comment: I will also add that the number of tilings can be computed with Knuth's algorithm for exact covers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is fascinating to be able to see all 1010 different arrangements. However, since it has to be a multiple of 4, I believe the answer should be 4040. Is that right? Another follow-up question: how do we know that this list is exhaustive?

Comment: @Hypatia Yes, a rectangle has 4 symmetries (left alone, horizontal fold, vertical fold, 180° rotation) so 1010 or 4040 will depend on what's meant by "different." As to exhaustive, Martin Brandenburg points to Knuth's algorithm for verifying this number. More generally, once you have the term polyomino (and pentomino) I think you can chase down the answer to this and similar questions!